# C# Remove all Items from List<T> if a property is in a List<string>

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a `List<T>` where T has a string property let's call it `Value`

Then I have a `List<string>` that contains some keywords.

How can I remove all items from the `List<T>` where the property Value matches one keywords from the `List<string>`?

Comment: Note that Styxxy solution (a nice one line!) doesn't use any LINQ. That elegant code is available since generics are in .NET (version 2.0, if I'm not wrong)

Comment: Side note: `HashSet<String>` is a better collection for *keywords* than `List<String>`, it performs `Contains` faster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`List<T>.RemoveAll Method (Predicate<T>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx), with a predicate that checks if the keywords list contains the Value.

Example console application:

```
public static class Program
{
    public class A
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var keywords = new List<string>() {"A", "B", "C", "D"};

        var aas = new List<A>()
        {
            new A() {Value = "A"},
            new A() {Value = "AA"},
            new A() {Value = "B"},
            new A() {Value = "AB"}
        };

        Console.WriteLine("Before remove:");
        aas.ForEach(a => Console.WriteLine("  A.Value = {0}", a.Value));

        aas.RemoveAll(a => keywords.Contains(a.Value));

        Console.WriteLine("After remove:");
        aas.ForEach(a => Console.WriteLine("  A.Value = {0}", a.Value));
    }
}
```

Output console:

```
Before remove:
  A.Value = A
  A.Value = AA
  A.Value = B
  A.Value = AB
After remove:
  A.Value = AA
  A.Value = AB
```

Comment: `keywords.Contains(a.Value)` here `a` can be `null` please add check for this case

Comment: @Vlad, nope, `aas` doesn't contain a single `null` element.

Comment: that's fine but in real world it's happens

Comment: This is just a sample to demonstrate how to use it. If it is possible that the list has a null value, it has to be checked indeed (but maybe in his application logic it is impossible that it contains a null value; you don't know that; that's his responsibility).

Answer (score 1):

```
public class test
{
    public string waarde { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var teBeRemoved = new List<string> {"een", "twee"};

        var totalList = new List<test> { new test { waarde = "een" }, new test { waarde = "drie" } };

        var filteredList  = totalList.Where(i => !teBeRemoved.Contains(i.waarde));

    }
}
```